# Reversing a circular doubly linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm attempting to implement a reverse() function on a circular doubly linked list.

Here is my code:

```
public void reverseCDLL() {

    if (head != null) {

       Node current = head, next, temp;

       do{

           next = current.getNextNode();
           temp = current.getPrevNode();
           current.setPrevNode(current.getNextNode());
           current.setNextNode(temp);
           current = next;

       }while(current != head);
    }
}
```

Input: `1 2 3 4`

Output: `1 4 3 2`

Expected Output: `4 3 2 1`

I'm very close to finishing this but one little thing is wrong and I just can't pin point what it is.

Any assistance / hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, @MathNoob, your algorithm is correct and it is reversing the circular linked list. But your head still points to 1 and hence the output is `1 4 3 2`. You can set the `head` to `head->prev` at last and it will work.

Comment: You can simply swap the head and tail, and then iterate over your linked list and swap the next and previous references for each node.Make sure to stop doing that after one full iteration.

Comment: @MathNoob, sorry it should be `head = head->next`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm works fine, you just need to change the head pointer to the correct value. When you reverse a linked list the head points to the last node, similarly in this case too the head should point to the last node.

```
public void reverseCDLL() {

    if (head != null) {

       Node current = head, next, temp;

       do{

           next = current.getNextNode();
           temp = current.getPrevNode();
           current.setPrevNode(current.getNextNode());
           current.setNextNode(temp);
           current = next;

       }while(current != head);
       head = head.getNextNode();
    }
}
```